# Selecting the first day of the month in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am using Hive (which is similar to SQL, but the syntax can be little different for the SQL users). I have looked at the other stackoverflow, but they seems to be in the SQL with different syntax.

I am trying to the get the first day of the month through this query. This one gives me today's day. For example, if today is 2015-04-30, then result would be 2015-04-01. Thanks!

```
select 
    cust_id,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd') as first_day_of_month_transaction
--DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) as first_day_of_month_transaction --SQL format. Not compatible in Hive.
from 
    customers;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the first day of the month, you can use:

```
date_add(<date>,
         1 - day(<date>) )
```

Applied to your expression:

```
date_add(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
         1 - day(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) 
        )
```

But this will work for any column in the right format.

Comment: This is actually giving me 2015-05-29. Not the first day of the month

Comment: @sharp . . . I fixed that.    The function should have been `date_sub()` or the sign inverted.

Comment: Thanks it works now. I didn't use date_sub() any where in the query. I used exactly from above.

Answer (score 21):

Try this

```
date_format(current_date,'yyyy-MM-01')
```

Comment: Great solution. Nice and compact!

Answer (score 6):

SELECT TRUNC(rpt.statement_date,'MM') will give you the first day of month.

Comment: This one is a simpler solution

Answer (score 3):

You can use this query to calculate the First day of the current month

```
Select date_add(last_day(add_months(current_date, -1)),1);
```

Instead of current_date, you can use the date field name.

- last_day => Gives the last day of current month
- add_months with -1 => Gives previous month
- date_add with 1 => Add one day

Answer (score 1):

Another way - `select concat(substring(current_date,1,7),'-01');`