# Get range of months between 2 dates

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql, date-range

For instance we have rows like

| in | out |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-03-03 |

and I need result with a list of months between, i.e.:

| in | out | between |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-03-03 | ["2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01"] |

to count then all months by some grouping.

There can be any day, but with kept months.
I try to reach this via combination of explode/posexplode, months_between, add_months, CTE, but have a lack of brain yet. One of:

```sql
select
    *,
    case
        when cast(
            ceil(abs(months_between(test.in, test.out))) as int
        ) > 1 then split(
            repeat(
                concat(add_months(test.in, 1), ','),
                cast(
                    ceil(abs(months_between(test.in, test.out))) as int
                )
            ),
            ','
        )
        else array(test.in)
    end btw
from test;
```

| in | out | btw |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-03-03 | ["2020-02-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-01", ""] |

I can't figure out how to increment months inside query with `months_between`. I believe there is some way, but I need a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lateral view posexplode to get rows with position numbers, add position to the IN date using add_months, collect_list to get an array, concatenate array using concat_ws if necessary.

Demo:

```sql
WITH test AS (
    SELECT '2020-01-06' dt_in, '2020-03-03' dt_out
)
SELECT dt_in, dt_out, 
       COLLECT_LIST(DATE_FORMAT(ADD_MONTHS(t.dt_in, pos), 'yyyy-MM-01')) AS `between`
FROM test t  
LATERAL VIEW OUTER POSEXPLODE(
    SPLIT(
        SPACE(
            CAST(CEIL(ABS(MONTHS_BETWEEN(DATE_FORMAT(t.dt_in, 'yyyy-MM-01'), t.dt_out))) AS INT) - 1
            ),
        ' '
        )
) e AS pos, x  
GROUP BY dt_in, dt_out;
```

Result:

```
     dt_in       dt_out       between   

2020-01-01       2020-03-03   ["2020-01-01","2020-02-01","2020-03-01"]
```

Comment: Yes, there need to be first day of month in dt_in. Hive doesn't contain built-in FIRST_DAY(), so I use ways from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972317/selecting-the-first-day-of-the-month-in-hive

Comment: @ruslan_krivoshein Edited: simplified a bit

Comment: Also for useness: in my case I omitted `COLLECT_LIST` and added _pos_ in `GROUP BY` clause to get expanded view of months between and thus I use it for required aggregations.